# How can I apply alternate color on cells with same values in app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation

I have google sheet having 2 columns called `start date`  and `end date`. while some date has repeated values. I want to find how many entries have same values. if it 2 or more cell has same values apply alternate colors.

All these i want to achive through app script/java script for google sheets.

please see two figures

Figure 1 = normal Figure

[image: By default Figure]

Figure 2 = what i want.

[image: Intended work]

So far, i have tried different method using conditional formatting by assigning column value to true and false. but no success yet.
any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This implementation assumes that the dates are exactly the same, down to the second. From what I see in the example you show, the seconds vary in the `start-date`.  Possible modifications to adjust for these problems:

1. Change the range from which they are evaluated from `A2:A` to `B2:B`. This assumes that the `end-date` is in column `B`. Simply change it to suit your needs.
2. Change the evaluation from equal to a subtraction, so that it does not evaluate if they are equal but that the difference between the two is no more than 5 seconds (or whatever amount you consider). Changing from `crrArr[idx - 1] !== crrArr[idx]` to `Math.abs(crrArr(idx-1) - crrArr[idx] > 5000)` for example.

###### `Code.gs`

```js
const sS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
function conditionalColors() {
  /* Filter the values to obtain true when the time changes */
  const values = sS
    /* Evaluate end-date `B2:B` */
    .getRange('A2:A')
    .getValues()
    .filter(n => n[0] !== '')
    .flat()
    .map(n => new Date(n).getTime())
    /* Math.abs(crrArr[idx-1] - crrArr[idx]) > 5000 */
    .map((n, idx, crrArr) => idx === 0 ? true : crrArr[idx-1] !== crrArr[idx])

  /* defining the colors*/
  const color1 = [204, 222, 188]
  const color2 = [238, 232, 170]
  let color = color1
  /* Loop to change the color every time we have a true */
  values.forEach((c, idx) => {
    if (c) {
      color = color === color1 ? color2 : color1
    }
    /* In the example Start Date is in A column (A===1) */
    /* And End Date in B Column */
    sS.getRange(idx + 2, 1).setBackgroundRGB(...color)
    sS.getRange(idx + 2, 2).setBackgroundRGB(...color)
  })
}
```

Example result using `Math.abs` (Notice A6):
[image]

###### Documentation:

- [setBackgroundRGB(red, green, blue)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setbackgroundrgbred,-green,-blue)
- [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: It create problem some times when my values has 2/3 empty cells in large data. the code asssign random color and dates are not same

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your conditional formatting

```
=MOD(ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,$A$2:$A2)),0),2)=1
```

[image]

If you want less precision (for instance only minute), you will have to adjust the formula with round this way

```
=MOD(ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(1/COUNTIF(round($A$2:$A2*60*24),round($A$2:$A2*60*24))),0),2)=1
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, do you know how can i apply this formula using app script

Comment: it is easier to apply by conditional formatting since it is done locally, a script is done by the server and is slower, moreover you have to remove colors (by conditional formatting, it's automatic), so I always recommend doing it by formula when possible!